# Loading JSON data using JQuery Mobile AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Hi I am working on my first mobile app for my WordPress blog. I have installed the JSON API plugin in my WordPress. I can get to my JSON Data using "example.com/api/get_recent_posts/".

I have created an HTML page with 2 pages. 1st page is just a list with with a button. The 2nd page is where I want to Load Datas from JSON. I have studied a bit of JQuery Mobile and learned that the best method to Load dynamic contents is AJAX.

I have seen lots of examples out there where pagebeforeshow, pageinit combined with either $.getJSON function or below $.ajax function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '',
    type: 'GET',
    error : function (){ document.title='error'; }, 
    success: function (data) {
        //
    }
});
```

Please I just need a guide on how to Load the JSON feeds using JQuery Mobile AJAX functions.

HTML Code:

```
<!-- Page: Home -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Menu</h1>
        </div><!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="listview">
            <p>This page is just a simple static page</p>
            <p><a href="#blogposts" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" id="devotionclick" data-role="button">Load my blogs</a>
        </div><!-- links -->
    </div><!-- page -->

<!-- Page: Blog Posts -->
    <div id="blogposts" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h2>My Blog Posts</h2>
        </div><!-- header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="postlist"> </ul><!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="load-more">Load More Posts...</div> 
    </div><!-- page -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know (and, I could be off) JQuery Mobile is just an extension of the regular JQuery, containing some additional events and methods that are mobile-specific. You can still use the $.ajax and $.getJSON as you're familiar with in JQuery, as long as you load the normal version of JQ as well.

If you're choosing JQuery Mobile hoping to increase mobile performance, try [ZeptoJS](http://zeptojs.com/)!

Comment: My understanding is $.getJSON is the short form for $.ajax but I read somewhere else that $.ajax is the replacement for $.getJSON and that it has more functionality.

Comment: getJSON taps in to ajax. They are essentially the same thing. However ajax has slightly more functionality that typically isnt needed. ajax is certainly not the replacement for getJSON, though.

Answer (score 0):

$.getJSON is a wrapper of the $.ajax API, with some preset parameters. I use $.getJSON almost exclusively, unless I need to do some customization to my request (synchronous instead of asynchronous, ...)

If you're going to need something on that second page, try this:

```
<div id="blogposts" data-role="page">
<script>
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#blogposts', function() {
     $.getJSON('http://example.com/api/get_recent_posts/', null, function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(p, post) {
              console.log(post.title); //Or whatever JSON keys you get back in return
              //Add them to a listview, or whatever you need to do.
         });
     });

});
</script>
<!-- rest of your page goes here -->
</div>
```

Do notice that you want to specify the page ID when you're instantiating the pagebeforeshow call.

Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and sample. It makes sense now

Comment: Is there any need to add a click Function after the 'pagebeforeshow' function?

Comment: Not unless you want to start pulling posts when someone taps a button. The code above will populate your listview (or whatever you want to do with the response) as soon as the page starts rendering... so by the time the page is loaded, the user should have all the data in there.

Comment: Clearly understand your point but how would the page load in first place without one clicking the button on the first page since the blogposts is the second page

Comment: Oh, that would also be handled in the first page. So a standard `a href="#blogposts"` would do the trick for navigation. (For more programmatic navigation, you can always go with the [changePage() API from jQuery Mobile](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/), but most of the time you can do just fine with standard links. Once you get to that page, the magic will happen automagically. :) )